# SSL 301 Redirect Errors- Joomla and Nginx

Tags: ssl, joomla, http-status-code-301, joomla2.5

My website is www.survivorssupply.com. I want to use SSL for my entire site because when I use SSL on only certain portions, the SSL certificate says certain parts were not delivered securely, not everything is secure, etc.

When I go into the Joomla admin panel, I set the entire site to force SSL for everything. I then get an issue with an endless redirect loop (301 error). My site is running the latest version of Joomla 2.5 on Nginx.

Is there some kind of rewrite I can use or does anyone know any Joomla tricks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably missing an extra parameter in the 443-section of your Nginx configuration. Add "fastcgi_param HTTPS on;" to the fastcgi-section.

@alfasin, Nginx doesn't use files like httpd.conf or .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

1. check your httpd.conf and .htaccess for 301 redirect rules regarding HTTPS
2. you receive the warning that parts of your site are not secured because you have embedded links which use HTTP instead of HTTPS - I would create a backup of teh site and start changing all the urls in the: template, articles, modules etc.